# How to display ECHO from VBScript in Command Prompt window with command line

Tags: vbscript

In batch file I have the command below:

```
WScript ABC.vbs
```

In `ABC.vbs`:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo "Hello"
```

When I run the batch file there is a pop-up message with the text "Hello". But what I want is showing the message "Hello" in the Command Prompt window like I do the right click on `ABC.vbs` and then select "Open with command prompt".

Comment: Change `wscript` to `cscript`

Comment: Use `cscript /nologo ABC.vbs` instead.

Comment: Use This : `Cscript //nologo ABC.vbs` To Run it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the two comments to use `cscript.exe ABC.vbs` as your command line, here is a function you can put in your .vbs script to ensure it always runs with the cscript engine, no matter how it's called.

```
Sub checkengine
  pcengine = LCase(Mid(WScript.FullName, InstrRev(WScript.FullName,"\")+1))
' BEGIN CALLOUT A
  If Not pcengine="cscript.exe" Then
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "CSCRIPT.EXE """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """"
    WScript.Quit
  End If
' END CALLOUT A
End Sub
```

From this site: [Forcing VBScript Files to Run in CScript Mode](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/forcing-vbscript-files-run-cscript-mode)

Put `Call checkengine` at the beginning of your vbscript. If it detects that cscript.exe is not in the command line, it relaunches the script with that engine.