# How to make connection of oracle DB using 32bit ODBC via VBScript

Tags: jenkins, cmd, vbscript, window, qtp

OS : Windows7
DB : Oracle 11 Enterprise Release 11.2.0.4.0
DSN: DSN created in ODBC in SYSWOW64

I have a vbs file that connect to Oracle DB and execute a query and return the result based on which I do some action.

```
Call db_connect(curSession, "DSN=INTDB;UID=RAKHSH;PWD=fdfg4qprd;")

strQuery="select count(*) from atmn.vc_run;"
call db_execute_query(curSession, strQuery)

intCount = db_get_rows_count_SQL(curSession, strQuery)

Public Function db_connect( byRef curSession ,DSN)
Set curSession = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
curSession.connectionstring = DSN
curSession.open

if Err.Number = 0 then
    db_connect=1
else
    db_connect=0
end If
End Function
```

I'm facing 2 problems:

1. When I double click this vbs file, it shows an error of architecture mismatch.
   I found the below thread and when I open the CMD from syswow64 and execute the script it works fine but when I double click it shows error 
   [How do I run a VBScript in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806584/how-do-i-run-a-vbscript-in-32-bit-mode-on-a-64-bit-machine)
2. I also need to run this from jenkin job using CSCRIPT, it shows the same message in jenkin console

I have been googling various solutions since last 2 days but unable to find any.

Answer (score 0):

Put this sub call at the top of your script:

```
RunAs32()
```

and include this sub in the

```
Sub RunAs32
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    If objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%") = "AMD64" Then 
        objShell.Run "c:\Windows\SysWow64\cscript.exe """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """",1,False
        WScript.Quit
    End If 
End Sub
```

If the cscript engine is running as a 64 bit, then the environmental variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` will be equal to `AMD64`, otherwise it will be `x86`. If it's `AMD64` you can relaunch the script in another process with the 32 bit version of cscript, then exit the original script.

Keep in mind though that if you typically double click on a script to run it, that will open **w**script.exe. You can check the calling engine with this line:

```
pcengine = LCase(Mid(WScript.FullName, InstrRev(WScript.FullName,"\")+1))
```

For a more complete answer to checking wscript vs cscript (and where the above line came from), check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150996/how-to-display-echo-from-vbscript-in-command-prompt-window-with-command-line)

Essentially you put a similar call to `checkengine` at the top of your script, then include the following sub:

```
Sub checkengine
  pcengine = LCase(Mid(WScript.FullName, InstrRev(WScript.FullName,"\")+1))
' BEGIN CALLOUT A
  If Not pcengine="cscript.exe" Then
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "CSCRIPT.EXE """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """"
    WScript.Quit
  End If
' END CALLOUT A
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Although, point 1 is solved by mealy changing the Open with option in properties but point 2 is still a challenge.

Comment: Can you try changing your default script host to cscript by running this from an administrative command prompt: `cscript.exe //H:CScript`

Comment: It works find on windows with 32bit CMD, using cscript.exe. I need to run this from Jenkin job now. Currently I'm using windows batch command plugin. But every time I execute the job, it is executed via 64bit CMD.